# Using a *.net domain as site URL or app domain

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to register an application so that I can implement log in with facebook on my site. The problem is that my domain ends with a .net hence I get an Error
App Domains: **********.net is not a valid domain.
Site URL is not a valid URL.

What could be the problem because when I use .com everything works fine.

Comment: I've got several apps registered to .net domains. That is not the issue. There must be a DNS error for your specific domain.

Comment: Apparently the problem is not the .net domain but my site url contains digits(site50.net).Is it not possible to specify a site URL or app domain with digits when creating a facebook application?

Comment: I got another domain with digits included and it worked fine with facebook apps. Site50.net may have had issues with DNS.

Comment: Site50.net is on the URI blacklist. http://admin.uribl.com